# Getting wrong permalink for view order in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I made a custom template for my-orders.php and to show specification of an order when I add the links, I get

view-order/?order="order number" as permalink. should me view-order/"ordernumber"

Code added:

```
?><tr class="order">
  <td class="order-number">
  <a href="<?php echo $order->get_view_order_url(); ?>">
  <?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>
 </a>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah I found this problem as well.

I spent some time trying to manipulate the woo commerce 2.1 before I realized it wasn't even being used.

Instead my theme actually had it's own account pages which didn't work with the 2.1 that was causing the problem. So I found a file in my theme called my-orders.php and had to yank out the part I didn't want:

The guilty code was caused by

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg('order', $order->id, get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'view_order' ) ) ) ); ?>">
```

and I just pulled out the offending non compatible with 2.1 bits:

```
<a href="<?php echo str_replace('?order=','',esc_url( add_query_arg('order', $order->id, get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'view_order' ) ) ) ) ); ?>">
```

I actually had to make this change in 2 place in this file

I'm just pulling about the old style url:

```
str_replace('?order=','',  OFFENDING STRING )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your permalink structure in the WordPress settings. `$order->get_view_order_url();` will give you pretty perma structure if your settings are correct.